# Yii : Error in defining an array

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii. I define an array as follows:

```
$simplified_list = array ( 
        [data] => array (
            [0] => array ( [name] => 4MB 1Day [data_volume] => 4 MB [tariff] => 2 [tariff_with_vat] => 2.3 ) 
            [1] => array ( [name] => 25MB 1Day [data_volume] => 25 MB [tariff] => 10 [tariff_with_vat] => 11.5 ) 
            [2] => array ( [name] => 100MB 7Day [data_volume] => 100 MB [tariff] => 40 [tariff_with_vat] => 46 ) 
            [3] => array ( [name] => 500MB 30Days [data_volume] => 500 MB [tariff] => 175 [tariff_with_vat] => 210.25 ) 
            [4] => array ( [name] => 1GB 30Days [data_volume] => 1024 MB [tariff] => 275 [tariff_with_vat] => 316.25 ) 
            [5] => array ( [name] => 2GB 30Days [data_volume] => 2048 MB [tariff] => 347 [tariff_with_vat] => 399 ) ) );
```

But there is a syntax error:

```
Syntax error:
expected: instanceof, OR, XOR, AND, ?, ';', ||, &&, |, ^, &, ==, !=, ===, !==, <=+, >=+, <, >, <<, >>, +, -, *, /, %, '.'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It's Yii. The language is PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not php notation. It should be this way:

```
$simplified_list = array(
    'data' => array(
        0 => array(
            'name' => '4MB 1Day',
            'data_volume' => '4 MB',
            'tariff' => 2,
            'tariff_with_vat' => 2.3,
        ),

        [...]
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try it this way:

```
$simplified_list = array ( 
        'data' => array (
            '0' => array ( 'name' => 4MB 1Day, 'data_volume' => '4 MB', 'tariff' => 2, 'tariff_with_vat' => 2.3 ) ...
```

More Information you can find here (your question has nothing to do with Yii, it's Basic PHP):
http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php